# Where would I add this add_action() code influencing the product admin view?

Tags: woocommerce, admin

I have a piece of code from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858236/how-to-add-remove-columns-in-woocommerce-admin-product-list/36041229#36041229) that customizes the way products are displayed in the admin view. It appears to be adding a WordPress hook using `add_action()`.

```
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'wpso23858236_product_column_offercode', 10, 2 );

function wpso23858236_product_column_offercode( $column, $postid ) {
    if ( $column == 'offercode' ) {
        echo get_post_meta( $postid, 'offercode', true );
    }
}
```

However, I am unclear where I have to place this code for it to have the desired effect.

Comment: I tried to edit it into a shape that works as a Stack Overflow question

Comment: This may be the answer https://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-do-i-put-add_action