# WooCommerce: Add new column in products list view and make it sortable

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

How can I add one more column (weight) in admin products list table list?

Comment: i guess you can find the solution here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858236/how-to-add-remove-columns-in-woocommerce-admin-product-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858236/how-to-add-remove-columns-in-woocommerce-admin-product-list) Hope this helps.

Comment: @MarshalDudeja thanks for the reference. which file do I edit? functions.php?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the new code in functions.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// Add product new column in administration
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'woo_product_weight_column', 20 );
function woo_product_weight_column( $columns ) {

    $columns['total_weight'] = esc_html__( 'Weight', 'woocommerce' );
        return $columns;

}
// Populate weight column
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'woo_product_weight_column_data', 2 );
function woo_product_weight_column_data( $column ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $column == 'total_weight' ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
                $weight = $product->get_weight();
        if ( $weight > 0 )
            print $weight . ' ' . esc_attr( get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit' ) );
        else print 'N/A';
    }
}
```

// Add CSS for column width

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_column_width');

function my_column_width() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">';
    echo 'table.wp-list-table .column-total_weight { width: 46px; text-align: left!important;padding: 5px;}';
    echo '</style>';
}
```

// make column sortable

```
function my_set_sortable_columns( $columns )
{
    $columns['total_weight'] = 'total_weight';
    return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_sortable_columns', 'my_set_sortable_columns' );
```

// Sorting function

```
function my_sort_custom_column_query( $query )
    {
        $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' );

        if ( 'total_weight' == $orderby ) {

            $meta_query = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => '_weight',
                    'compare' => '>', // see note above
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => '_weight',
                ),
            );

            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        }
    }

    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_sort_custom_column_query' );
```

**Tested OK with WooCommerce 3.5.7**

Comment: This seems to work. only question is how can i increase the column size, now its very narrow. Also is there a way to make this column sortable?

Comment: super, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

A new column in the orders list that displays the correct weight with the weight unit defined in WooCommerce settings. Simply place that code in **functions.php** in your theme folder:

```php
// Store cart weight in the database
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'woo_add_cart_weight');
function woo_add_cart_weight( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    
    $weight = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight;
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_cart_weight', $weight );
}
// Add order new column in administration
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'woo_order_weight_column', 20 );
function woo_order_weight_column( $columns ) {
    $offset = 8;
    $updated_columns = array_slice( $columns, 0, $offset, true) +
    array( 'total_weight' => esc_html__( 'Weight', 'woocommerce' ) ) +
    array_slice($columns, $offset, NULL, true);
    return $updated_columns;
}
// Populate weight column
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'woo_custom_order_weight_column', 2 );
function woo_custom_order_weight_column( $column ) {
    global $post;
 
    if ( $column == 'total_weight' ) {
        $weight = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cart_weight', true );
        if ( $weight > 0 )
            print $weight . ' ' . esc_attr( get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit' ) );
        else print 'N/A';
    }
}
```

Try to use this code.