# Is it possible to show in woocommerce products admin panel the aggregate rating of a product?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to figure out if it is possible, when I display my product list in woocommerce admin next to the name of the product to show the stars and rating of those products which have ratings.

thank you

Comment: Have you tried something like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23937010/464538

Comment: Yes but how I populate it with ratings?